# How come Ace editor won't work correctly in my Meteor/Angular application?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, meteor, angular-ui, ace-editor

I've created an [example Meteor application](http://meteor-ace.meteor.com/) which integrates with [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) and embeds the [Ace editor](http://ace.c9.io/) via the [UI.Ace](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace) Angular directive. However, although the editor shows up, it doesn't accept input. In Chromium/Chrome it's only after I open or close Developer Tools that the editor reacts and becomes responsive to input (the editor must react to some change in the browser's state AFAICT).

Basically, how do I fix my app so that the Ace component works and accepts input? Full source code for my app is available at [github](https://github.com/aknuds1/meteor-ace).

## Code

### HTML

#### angular.html

```
<div class="content pure-g-r" data-ng-controller="MeteorCtrl">
    <header>
        <nav id="menu" class="pure-menu pure-menu-open pure-menu-fixed pure-menu-horizontal">
            <div class="pure-u-1-5">
                <div class="pure-menu-heading">Meteor-Ace</div>
            </div>

            <ul class="pure-u-4-5">
                <li data-ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems">
                    <a href="{{menuItem.address}}">{{menuItem.name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <article id="content">
        <div class="content-ribbon">
                <div data-ng-view></div>
        </div>
        <footer class="pure-u-1">
            Made with the excellent <a href="http://meteor.com/">Meteor</a> framework and
            <a href="http://meteor.com/">AngularJS</a>. © 2013 Arve Knudsen
        </footer>
    </article>
</div>
```

#### partials/home.html

```
<div class="pure-u-1-5">
    <div id="sidebar">Sidebar Content</div>
</div>

<div class="pure-u-4-5">
    <div id="editor-container">
        <h1><a href="http://ace.c9.io/">Ace</a> Editor Demo</h1>

        <div data-ui-ace></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CoffeeScript

#### app.coffee

```
require(["angular", "underscore"], (angular, _) ->
  homeUrl = "/"

  app = angular.module('meteorapp', ['meteor', 'ui.ace'],
    ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) ->
      $routeProvider.when(homeUrl, templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: "MeteorCtrl")
      $routeProvider.otherwise(redirectTo: homeUrl)
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
    ])

  class MenuItem
    constructor: (@name, @address) ->
      @isSelected = false

  app.controller("MeteorCtrl", ["$scope", ($scope) ->
    $scope.menuItems = [
      new MenuItem("Home", homeUrl),
    ]
  ])

  app.controller("HomeCtrl", ["$scope", ($scope) ->
    markSelected($scope, homeUrl)
  ])

  markSelected = ($scope, url) ->
    _($scope.menuItems).each((item) =>
      item.isSelected = item.address == url
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you create a plunker? thx

Comment: @sza Had never heard of Plunker up till now. Will see what I can do.

Comment: @sza I don't think Plunker is the way to go for this project, as the project's too dependent on the Meteor framework. I'd have to rewrite with Plunker in mind, and I don't see the point since the application is oriented around Meteor in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that editor isn't resized properly.
Try updating ace version or calling `editor.resize()` after ui is ready.

Comment: Since you suggest updating the Ace version, is this fixed in newer versions?

Comment: The new version fixed several bugs with resizing.
I am not 100% sure if it fixes this particular bug since i couldn't get your app running locally, and on the page you linked, everything is minified together and undebuggable.

Comment: OK thanks, will try to update Ace (although it depends on my being able to update the Meteor package I'm using). I've also been informed of a Meteor-specific version of Ace which might(?) work better.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/mad-eye/meteor-reactive-ace) one seems to use latest ace build

Comment: Yes, that's the one I was informed of earlier :)

Comment: Updating the Ace version does solve the immediate problem, thanks. I'm wondering though if reactive-ace would be the better choice in the long run, in combination with Meteor, going to see if I can make that work.

Comment: I had a more detailed look at it don't think it's very useful, basically adds some wrapper for ace.  

Also i see that in your example all the files from ace directory are included, this is bad since ace have many modes. It will be better to let ace loads files when it needs them  

var config = require("ace/config");config.set("basePath", "js/modules/ace/build/src-min");